# Can I use Elbrus as my Commander?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

[Elbrus, the Binding Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elbrus%2C%20the%20Binding%20Blade), is a Legendary Artifact - Equipment that transforms into Withengar Unbound, a Black Legendary Demon. Can I use Elbrus/Withengar as a Commander, and if I can, is my deck colorless or black?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's [an official ruling from Sheldon Mennery](http://mtgcommander.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=11327&start=11), who is the authoritative source for Commander rulings:

> [O] Elbrus is not playable as a General, and its color identity is Black.

Answer (score 10):

[Elbrus, the Binding Blade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elbrus%2C%20the%20Binding%20Blade) is not a Legendary Creature, so it cannot be your Commander. It doesn't matter that it could become a creature. In fact, I'd be surprise if there is a card that couldn't become a creature.

> 711.2a In every zone other than the battlefield, and also on the battlefield with its front face up, a double-faced card has only the characteristics of the front face.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected this might be the case (though it's saddening), but I wanted confirmation from folks who understand Commander better, since I'm assembling my first-ever deck for it now.

Comment: It's not really a Commander question, because you already knew the Commander part. It's really a question about double-faced cards. Added the relevant rule to the answer.

Comment: @ikegami I think it is a Commander question. Because what it's actually asking is "Does the back of the card count _during deck-building_?" And the answer it's necessarily obvious because the precedent in Commander is that it can, based on how we handle the color identity of cards like Garruk Relentless.

Comment: @Alex P, Fine, then no, it's not like color identity. It merely looks if the card is a Legendary Creature.

Comment: @AlexP Deckbuilding isn't the issue. The issue is the Command Zone, which counts as a zone other than the battlefield. The back face doesn't show in the Command Zone, so you can't cast it as a commander.

Comment: @Alex P, Color identity has 903.4c to look at more than just the card.

Comment: When I said "it's" above I meant "isn't." _Isn't_ obvious. >.>

Comment: @Alex P, No worries, that's what I read